# How to use multiple fields in @JsonTypeInfo annotation?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm receiving next json from FE:

```
{
  "type1":"A",
  "type2":"B"
}

enum Type1 {
   A,
   B
}

enum Type2 {
   A,
   B
}
```

And base on those two fields I want to map json to specific class. For example I have:

```
class Base {
   Type1 type1;
   Type2 type2;
}

class Ab extends Base {

}
```

Object should be `Ab` in case of `type1 = A and type2 = B`

```
class Ba extends Base {

}
```

Object should be `Ba` in case of `type1 = B and type2 = a`

For this case we have `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation but it works only with one field. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: You can use a custom resolver with[`@JsonTypeResolver`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonTypeResolver.html)

Comment: @Aaron hmm actually I can't get both fields to form an output object, maybe you have an example ?

Comment: I don't have an example handy, but maybe [this article](https://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2013/09/10/custom-polymorphic-type-handling-with-jackson/) helps?

Comment: I've tried exactly from that article. There is no way to get both fields in resolver.

Comment: @OrestKyrylchuk i think you will have to use custom deserializer/serializer instead(

Comment: @varren yep that would work, but my idea was to get around deserializer/serializer (